# Its possible update a controller and/or a view from a database model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a newbie in C#, I made a search but I couldn't find anything that help me. I am using C#, ASP.NET MVC 4, Visual Studio 2015, EF6 and a MySQL database.

I have a database, I created my web application, connected the app with the database and created a CRUD. I did this creating a controller with: a View and Entity Framework.

Now I have to change my database, I add a column to a table, and in my database model in VS I update the model with "Update model from the database", the model  has been updated OK. I compile my project but now, the controller and the view (of course) do not show the new column.

How can I do this? It is possible to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can edit views as u want.

Comment: Sounds like you scaffold the controller. Just edit the `.cshtml` and add the relevant `field` and modify the `controller`. You are new to C# best to do it yourself and learn rather than having VS generate junks for you.

Comment: @12seconds then, every change that I make in my Database, I have to manually update it in my controller and view?? This is your recommendation that this is the best I can do?

Comment: @Mary, yes... I'm not sure what you are expecting but VS doesn't magically does it for you when you make changes to database...

Comment: @12seconds ok, thanks then, now I do not know if I left my question or I delete

Comment: Do not delete. If you thought it was a question to be asked then someone also can ask same question. For your question I agree to @12seconds. It s better to make everything manuel.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can create a new view of type of your changed model. Or you can open the cshtml file and write html for new column as other columns of that type have.